# Database error 1054 while doing query Unknown column 'active' in 'where clause'

Tags: mysql, phplist

I want integrate phpList for my website. Currently i am in development process.

I created database then i created table with this SQL(i m nt sure table structure is right or not).

```
CREATE TABLE `phplist_subscribepage` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `data` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`)
)
```

After doing this i am getting this message when i am trying to run index.php

```
Database error 1054 while doing query Unknown column 'active' in 'where clause'
Database error 1054 while doing query Unknown column 'active' in 'where clause'
```

I am totally new to phpList. i couldn't figure out what could be the prblm.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Update the question with the SQL-query in index.php. I think the error lies there.

Comment: The message is saying that there should be a column called `active` in your table. You should follow whatever installation instructions that phpList supplies to create the tables, since doing it by guesswork will take a long time.

Comment: @Treps : which SQL query ? there are many queries.

Comment: @MikeW : Instructions which i followed it jst says create database.  Do you have a link of any other document which guides all the way ?

Comment: Don't you get what row in the code the "Database error 1054 while doing query Unknown column 'active' in 'where clause'" message comes from? Search for "active" in the code and se what query it is. I belive the SQL-query says SELECT ...,...,... active,... FROM .... and "active" doesn't exists.

Comment: actually this message is displayed when i tried to open admin panel of phpList. Which only displayed small message,not the actual message. I solved this when i reinstalled it. Thanks for trying to help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be i did something wrong in previous installation. when i re-installed it, it started working.